# SQL TO SSIS derived column month name and 1ST of month

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following as sql

SQL TO SSIS derived column month name and 1ST of month

DATENAME(MM,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) --month name

DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) --date 1st of month

cant get these to work as derived columns in SSIS

how do I convert please team

Comment: What version of SQL Server/SSIS are you running?

Comment: 2010 version please team

Comment: Are those in your SQL query or in you Derived column? It looks like you're using the SQL syntax and not what SSIS uses. Also 2010 isn't a valid version of SQL Server. That may be the visual studio client you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment about *going back 3 months*, I decided to take a different approach.

Create the following SSIS Variables below (I will describe the expression to be assigned to each)

[image]

**DateIncrementDecrement** will contain the number of months to add or subtract from the current date (3 for plus 3 months and negative 3 (-3) for minus 3 months).  Altering the value of this variable with successive runs should give you the correct results.

**AdjustedDate** expression is

`DATEADD("MONTH", @[User::DateIncrementDecrement], getdate())`

**FirstOfMonth** expression is

`(DT_WSTR,10)(DT_DBDATE)(DATEADD("DAY",-(DAY(@[AdjustedDate])) + 1,@[AdjustedDate]))`

**MonthName** expression is

`(DT_WSTR,15)(MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 1 ? "January" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 2 ? "February" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 3 ? "March" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 4 ? "April" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 5 ? "May" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 6 ? "June" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 7 ? "July" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 8 ? "August" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 9 ? "September" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 10 ? "October" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 11 ? "November" : MONTH(@[User::AdjustedDate]) == 12 ? "December" : "")`

In your Derived Column Transformation Editor, create two new derived columns

[image]

**MonthName** expression is

`(DT_WSTR,15)@[User::MonthName]`

**FirstOfMonth** expression is

`@[User::FirstOfMonth]`

Comment: hi, this is great thank you. What happens if I need to please go back 3 months? got to be honest , hence why I was using the DATEADD(mm part. e.g so date is 01/10/2018, and month is October

Comment: @pete - you're welcome :)